# phonegap XMLHttpRequest response text returning empty in galaxy s4 but not galaxy note

Tags: javascript, android, json, cordova, xmlhttprequest

I'm having problems connecting to my server to check credentials for my phone application, in which I'm using phonegap to develop it.

I've already checked out these questions, but they're not giving me what I'm looking for

[HTTP Requests in Phonegap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13585854/http-requests-in-phonegap)

[HTTP methods in PhoneGap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8727627/http-methods-in-phonegap)

I've read up on the subject and have made multiple sites using get requests, so I have a pretty good understanding on the matter, I'm just not sure what's going on.

http://simonmacdonald.blogspot.com/2011/12/on-third-day-of-phonegapping-getting.html

Here's what my code looks like:

```
login.onclick = function() {
  var req = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
  req.open('GET', 'myServer'+username.value+".json", true);
  req.send();

  req.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (req.readyState == 4) {
          if( (req.status == 200) || (req.status == 0) ) {
              var json = JSON.parse(req.responseText);
              if(json.length > 0) {
                  if((json[0]["username"] == username.value) && (json[0]["phoneCred"] == password.value)){
                              localStorage.setItem("loggedIn",username.value);
                              location.reload();
                  }
                  else {
                      alert("Incorrect password");
                  }
              }
              else {
                  alert("Incorrect username");
              }
          }
          else {
              alert("Error talking to server");
          }
      }
  }
};
```

I added the req.status == 0 into the one if, and now my button is completely unresponsive, I was at least getting the alert that I wasn't talking to the server. If anyone has any insight, it would be much appreciated!

okay so i had a couple of errors in my code, in which i fixed so here's my updated code:

```
login.onclick = function() {
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open('GET', 'myServer'+username.value+'.json', true);
req.send();

alert('myServer'+username.value+'.json');
req.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (req.readyState == 4) {
        if( (req.status == 200) || (req.status == 0) ) {

            //alert(req.responseText.length);
            alert(req.responseText);
            if(req.responseText.length > 0) {
                var json = JSON.parse(req.responseText); 
                if( (json[0].username == username.value) && (json[0].phoneCred == password.value) ){
                            localStorage.setItem("loggedIn",username.value);
                            location.reload();
                }
                else {
                    alert("Incorrect password");
                }
            }
            else {
                alert("Incorrect username");
            }
        }
        else {
            alert("Error talking to server");
        }
    }
}
};
```

i have two phone on which i've been testing on, and it worked on my galaxy note, but not on my galaxy   s4 if that might be a hint towards anything.

i also changed my access tag in my xml file to

```
<access origin=".*" />
```

after i did some reading from

[Phonegap + Android status=0 returned from webservice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11230685/phonegap-android-status-0-returned-from-webservice)

[phonegap XMLHttpRequest responseText empty with android but contain data in iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8270385/phonegap-xmlhttprequest-responsetext-empty-with-android-but-contain-data-in-ipho)

and

[Empty responseText from XMLHttpRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1941340/empty-responsetext-from-xmlhttprequest)

but my galaxy s4 still doesnt seem to receive any data from the server. It may be the same origin policy or some setting for internet access that I'm unsure about. If anyone has any suggestions, I would be very appreciative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed it. I needed to add

```
<access origin="http://google.com" />
```

to the config.xml file, where google.com was my own server. Phonegap has some nice documentation now that you can see here

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/guide_appdev_whitelist_index.md.html#Whitelist%20Guide

Comment: Thanks for posting up your solution